Calling Sagemaker endpoint using postman using temporary credentials
I have configured my AWS CLI to use profile using SSO. I have referred this doc AWS Documentation
I want to use postman to call Sagemaker endpoint. Is there a way to do it. I tried giving my credentials in postman but it returned 404 error.
Some additional details -
The Sagemaker endpoint uses VPC.

404 error means the resource (endpoint URL you hit) was was not found. So the error is unrelated to the credential. Please make sure the endpoint is reachable from the environment you are usin Postman.
